# Laravel 5.1 create 5 minute cookie then return view

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-5.1

I want to set 5 minutes cookie then return to view,

But if i use view in Response, cookie loses. And when i back to index page, i can't see that cookie. Because it lost.

But if i return response without view, it works perfectly.

```
$response = new Illuminate\Http\Response();
return $response->withCookie(cookie('yes', 'value', 5));
```

This works perfectly.

But this is not:

```
$response = new Illuminate\Http\Response(view('somepage'));
return $response->withCookie(cookie('yes', 'value', 5));
```

How can i create view after set up cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Cookie\CookieJar;

class NewClass
{
    public function handle(Request $requestVal, CookieJar $cookieVal)
    {
        $cookieVal->queue(cookie('yourCookie', $requestVal->value, 5000));
        return redirect('somepage');
    }
}
```

Comment: Syed this is not creating view; i have a lot of business in controller then i pass data to the view so i have to create view after set up the cookie